# $A_5$ is a simple group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

We need to prove that $A_5$ is a simple group.
We consider the representatives of the cycle types of even permutations as follows : $$ (1) , (123) , (12345) , (12)(34)$$

Now we want , say , conjugates of (123) in $A_5$ ,

So first we find the conjugates of (123) in $S_5$ , which is given by $ 3! (5-3)!$ which is 6 ,

Now how to decide that how many of these are in $A_5$ , could anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\vert H \vert \neq 1$. Let $\sigma \in H$ such that $\#\{n : \sigma(n) = n\}$ is maximal and $\sigma \neq e$. The goal is to show that $\sigma$ must be a $3$-cycle. Write $\sigma$ as a product of disjoint cycles
$$\sigma = \tau_1\tau_2 \cdots \tau_{n}.$$
We have two cases: either all the $\tau_i$ are $2$-cycles, or at least one of the two $\tau_i$ is not a $2$-cycle. In the first case, let
$$\sigma = (a_1 a_2)(a_3 a_4)\cdots(a_{2m-1} a_{2m}).$$
Now since $\sigma \neq e$, we may choose $r$ such that $\sigma(r) = r$. Let $\tau = (a_3 a_4 r)$. Since $H$ is normal and $\tau \in A_n$, we have $\pi = \tau\sigma\tau^{-1}\sigma^{-1} \in H$. Check that $\pi$ fixes $a_1, a_2$. But then by the maximality of our choice of $\sigma$, we must have that $\pi = e$, i.e. $\tau\sigma = \sigma\tau$. Check that $\tau\sigma(3) \neq \sigma\tau(3)$ to get a contradiction. Therefore $\sigma$ cannot be a product of disjoint $2$-cycles, i.e. at least one of the $\tau_i$ is not a $2$-cycle. See if you can finish this case to conclude that $\sigma$ must be a $3$-cycle.

Answer (score 0):

All of the conjugates of $(123)$ are in $A_5$, as all of the $3$-cycles are even permutations. You're trying to show that any nontrivial normal subgroup of $A_5$ is the whole group. One method is this: Show that $A_5$ is generated by $3$-cycles, then show that any normal subgroup $N$ of $A_5$ must contain a $3$-cycle by considering an element of $N$ which fixes a maximal number of symbols $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Then show that any two $3$-cycles are conjugate in $A_5$. This method can be used to show that all of the alternating groups $A_n$ where $n \geq 5$ are simple.

Comment: Just one more thing , I got the conjugations of $(1) , (123) , (12345) ,(12)(34)$ , which are the representatives of different conjugate classes as {1,20,12,12,15} , now let $H$ is a normal subgroup , how to show that $|H|= 1$ or $|H| = 60$ ? Thanks in advance !